# Is there a method in pandas to display unique levels of dataframe in a clean table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying out using python instead of R for a survey analysis. When I initially explore survey data, I like to print out the unique categorical values in the data set. This is useful for seeing how the data was storied by the survey tool and useful for comparing with the options as written in the survey.

Using df['Example'].unique() I can find the levels. However I would like to be able to print them cleanly in a Notebook. I like the way pandas dataframes look when printed in the notebook but dataframes require the data to be in a observation vs feature format. I was unable to successfully coerce the levels of various counts into a DataFrame.

Is there a built in function to display the levels of a dataframe using pandas? Otherwise, any suggestions on how to do this?

For now, I am simply printing on the screen for reference. I'm then saving to a csv file to review on excel.

```
maxLevels = 21
dfUnique = df.nunique() < maxLevels
fixedLevelColnames = list(dfUnique[dfUnique == True].index)

with open('Levels.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as levelFile:
    for name in fixedLevelColnames:
        levels = [str(level) for level in df[name].unique()]
        levels.sort()
        levelString = '{} has {} Unique Level(s),{}\n'.format(str(name),df[name].nunique(),",".join(levels))
        print(levelString.replace(',',', '))
        levelFile.write(levelString)
```

An example output:
*A has 5 Unique Level(s), Don't know, Mildly, Moderately, No, Severely

B has 3 Unique Level(s), Don't know, No, Yes

C has 3 Unique Level(s), Don't know, No, Yes*

Comment: Can you share a sample dataframe we can use?

Comment: I'll add a dataframe example for what I think is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                   'B': [10, 8, 6, 4, 4],
                   'C': [9, 7, 4, 3, 9]})
df

    A   B   C
0   a   10  9
1   a   8   7
2   b   6   4
3   b   4   3
4   b   4   9


cat_list = [df[c].value_counts().to_frame() for c in df.columns]

catted_df = pd.concat(cat_list, axis=1)
catted_df.fillna(0).astype(int)

    A   B   C
3   0   0   1
4   0   2   1
6   0   1   0
7   0   0   1
8   0   1   0
9   0   0   2
10  0   1   0
a   2   0   0
b   3   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a little different from what i'm looking for but gave me an idea for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The following creates a dataframe that I was hoping for.

If there is a built-in function that does something similar that would still be good to know.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No'],
                   'B': ['Yes', 'No', "I don't know", 'No'],
                   'C': ['Yes', 'No', "I don't know", "I'm not telling you"]})
df

'''
     A             B                    C
0  Yes           Yes                  Yes
1   No            No                   No
2  Yes  I don't know         I don't know
3   No            No  I'm not telling you
'''

max_levels = 10
df_levels = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,max_levels), columns=df.columns)
for c in df.columns:
    df_levels[c] = pd.Series([df[c].nunique(), *df[c].unique()])
print(df_levels.fillna('-').T)

'''
   0    1   2             3                    4  5  6  7  8  9
A  2  Yes  No             -                    -  -  -  -  -  -
B  3  Yes  No  I don't know                    -  -  -  -  -  -
C  4  Yes  No  I don't know  I'm not telling you  -  -  -  -  -
'''
```